# Residual plot transformation question

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, residuals

I need some help figuring out what kind of transformation to do on a residual plot. Essentially, I have to make a residual plot of a player's salary in the NBA compared with their points scored.

Here is the distribution code and plot:

```
plot(salary ~ pts, xlab = "Points", ylab = "Salary", pch = 20, bty = "n")
abline(pts.b0, pts.b1, col="red")
```

[image: Distrib Plot]

For the residual, I wrote this:

```
linreg = lm(salary ~ pts)
resids = linreg$resid
plot(pts, resids, xlab = "Points", ylab = "Residual", pch = 20, bty = "n")
abline(h=0,col="red")
```

And I got this graph:
[image]

Now I don't think this is a very good residual plot because of its heteroskedastic? so I tried to perform a log transformation

```
linreg_log = lm(salary ~ logpts)
resids_log = linreg_log$resid
plot(logpts, resids_log, xlab = "Logarithm of Points", ylab = "Residuals", pch = 20, bty = "n")
abline(h=0,col="red")
```

And I got this graph:
[image]

and this plot wasn't really better than the first.

Then I tried sqrt of points and still no go:

```
sqrtpts = sqrt(pts)
linreg_sqrt = lm(salary ~ sqrtpts)
resids_log = linreg_sqrt$resid
plot(logpts, resids_log, xlab = "Square Root of Points", ylab = "Residuals", pch = 20, bty = "n")
abline(h=0,col="red"
```

[image]

Here is the log of salary:
[image]

And salary^(1/2):
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on what transformation I should perform? Unfortunately after searching I didn't really much helpful information that is R related to this.

Comment: You seem to have some negative salaries in these data.  How does that happen?

Comment: I think it is because it is the residual, the negative values come from the observed value minus the predicted value. If you look at the first graph there are no negative salaries just a lot of people paid under a million. Which is lower than the predicted value hence all the negatives; so they are doing worse than I predicted. I think this is called over-predicting. Which kinda has me stumped for I am unsure how to transform the residual plot to not over-predict.

Comment: Try log transforming salary instead of points.

Comment: Your problem is heteroskedasticity, not homoskedasticity. Hetero = different; homo = same.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you! Just noticed that typo as well while writing another comment!

Comment: @BigBendRegion Thank you! While still heteroskedastic, log probably looks the best. I think it may just be due to the fact that in the NBA there is a minimum player salary, and when you factor in a salary cap there are just a ton of players being paid under what they should be.

Comment: I was referring to the original plot, not the residual plot: the lowest values are slightly--but quite clearly--negative.

Comment: @whuber Are you sure that's not an optical illusion? When I put a ruler on my screen I see some points that appear to be exact zeros but no negative values.

Comment: @Roland I agree: when one magnifies this image and carefully measures its contents, four of the points look like they might be true zeros and six more points are close.  And that's exactly my point: how can we be expected to provide good advice when the presentation of the data depends on the absence (or presence) of a possible optical illusion?  Given there is a substantial (and positive) minimum salary in this league, what are those near-zero salaries and what do they represent?